# What is this $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ that Loomis and Sternberg talk about in their book "Advanced Calculus"?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

The authors introduce the "three dimensional Euclidean space", $\mathbb{E}^{3}$, without defining it, but explains that there is a correspondence between $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ and $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ by picking an arbitrary point $O$ in $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ as the origin, and three unit points $Q_{1}, Q_{2}, Q_{3}$ such that not all four points lie in a plane. Every point $\mathbf{X}$ in $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ thus determines a triple $\mathbf{x} = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ living in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$.

The correspondence isn't explained in detail, but they list four "theorems" about the correspondence which they claim to be quite tricky to prove, and assume them instead. They are:

1. $T: \mathbb{E}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{3}$ as explained above, is a bijection.
2. Two line segments $AB$ and $XY$ in $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ are equivalent (same length, parallel, equally directed) if and only if the vectors  $\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a}$ and  $\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ are equal.
3. If $X \neq 0$, then $Y$ is on the line through $O$ and $X$ if and only if $\mathbf{y} = t \mathbf{x}$ for some $t \in \mathbf{R}$.
4. If the axes in $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ are orthonormal, then then the length $|OX|$ equals $(\sum_{i=1}^{3} x_{i})^{2}$.

How in the world would someone go about proving these theorems without knowing what $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ is? Intuitively, the authors seem to imply that it's the familiar $3$-dimensional space that contains points, lines, and planes that we're all familiar with. But it's hard to say without a definition of Euclidean space. Furthermore, is $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ a vector space? If it is, then I'm assuming that its base field is $\mathbf{R}$, but if that's the case, why do we even bother with $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ in the first place, when we can work with the vector space $\mathbf{R}^{3}$?

Comment: $\Bbb E^3$ is a space in which we can do geometry of planes, lines, spheres and such (if I understood it correctly). It can, for instance, be a space described by [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms). One reason to work with $\Bbb E^3$ instead of $\Bbb R^3$ is that things that can be proven without imposing structure like a coordinate system and vector addition, usually have more elegant and intuitive proofs when doing without that structure.

Comment: I suggest to look at Wikipedia page on "Euclidean space". Let me copy two sentences: "Mathematicians denote the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space by $E^n$ if they wish to emphasize its Euclidean nature, but $R^n$ is used as well since the latter is assumed to have the standard Euclidean structure, and these two structures are not always distinguished. ... A Euclidean space is not technically a vector space but rather an affine space, on which a vector space acts by translations, or, conversely, a Euclidean vector is the difference (displacement) in an ordered pair of points, not a single point."

Comment: Back in the Olden Days (when Loomis & Sternberg wrote their textbook), there was a high school course in geometry.  Synthetic geometry.  With proofs.  Not with coordinates.  So those guys assumed that college students had knowledge of that material.

Comment: @GEdgar That would mean $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ is just the intuitive space to do synthetic geometry, which isn't as rigorous as $\mathbf{R}^{3}$. I suppose one could say that Loomis & Sternberg had Hilbert's axioms in mind, which means $\mathbb{E}^{3}$ is... an arbitrary model of the axioms?

Comment: @MaxisJaisi ... At the Loomis & Sternberg level, let's just say Euclidean geometry has a second-order completeness property. And do not assume anything is known to the students about model theory.  I guess similarly when we write $\mathbf R$ we mean "any model" for the second-order notion "complete ordered field".

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space but due to the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\textbf{e}^j = (0,....,1=x_j,0,...,0)$ forms a basis for $j = 1,...,n$ then $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow \textbf{v} = \sum_j v_j \textbf{e}^J$ i.e the coordinate representation of $\textbf{v}$ is the $n$-tuple $(v_1,...,v_n)$. We define $\mathbb{E}^n = (\mathbb{R}^n, \| \cdot \|)$ i.e $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the standard euclidean topology induced by the distance metric (hence the $\mathbb{E}$).

These two spaces are usually identified since $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the coordinate chart $\varphi = (x^1,...,x^n)$ where $x^j(\textbf{v}) := v_j$ turns $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a manifold trivially, how? Let $\mathcal{B} = \{\textbf{e}^j: j = 1,...,n\}$ then we see that $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n_{\mathcal{B}}$ defined by $\textbf{v} \mapsto \textbf{v}_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a linear isomorphism i.e we identify $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n_{\mathcal{B}}$ and with this $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n_{\mathcal{B}} \to \mathbb{E}^n$ becomes a global chart which is just the identity i.e a smooth diffeomorphism.

Really we should define $\psi =  \varphi \circ \Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{E}^n$ but since we know that we can transfer the necessary information about $\mathbb{R}^n_{\mathcal{B}}$ by a linear isomorphism (i.e a structure preserving map), we can suppress this map for now and reference it when need be. The same identification is done is calculus when you learn about arc-length parameterizations and defining the Frenet-Frame for an arbitrary curve with constant speed i.e $\textbf{T}(s):= \textbf{T}(t)$. But really $s,t$ are related by a diffeomorphism i.e a structure preserving map (in this case, manifold structure) i.e $\textbf{T}(s) = \textbf{T}(\beta(t))$.  In sum, $\mathbb{E}^n$ is the model space of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I hope this helps.